# Monero RPC Help

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc

I'm having an issue with using the Monero RPC.

My node is all setup and working and using `monero-wallet-cli` I can create a wallet, send funds etc, however when I try to use the RPC I get the following error.

I'm new to playing around with Monero node's RPC calls etc but I'm trying to learn and I'm sure its something really silly.

```
root@localhost:/walllet# monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18081 --rpc-login deleted:deleted --wallet-file wallet --prompt-for-password
This is the RPC monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero
daemon to work correctly.

Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.3.0-release)
Logging to monero-wallet-rpc.log
2022-03-27 10:46:04.818 W Loading wallet...
Wallet password: 
2022-03-27 10:46:11.683 W Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: (DELETED)
2022-03-27 10:46:12.000 W Transaction extra has unsupported format: <cb3856dee480e70255a403bb12d0e53c392abd89e8fbaacc70bb919f58e822ad>
2022-03-27 10:46:12.000 W Transaction extra has unsupported format: <792bddbc428562d20354e40d5d6e5ec95897b0a166449ab0ebb19a21371c3b2a>
2022-03-27 10:46:12.001 W Transaction extra has unsupported format: <bb064c4b76631b8e74ff0c5f5fae55fd2cad116cf5d9341b865dddda150b340c>
2022-03-27 10:46:12.001 W Transaction extra has unsupported format: <da198baca3a5e7268d9da22fb10bbf1b0c807ed9e3ac80cd1621b9e367910149>
2022-03-27 10:46:12.116 W Background mining not enabled. Run "set setup-background-mining 1" in monero-wallet-cli to change.
```

This is the part I'm struggling with. I don't get why I cant bind to port 18081 on 127.0.0.1 as nothing else is bound to it (as far as I'm aware).

```
2022-03-27 10:46:12.116 I Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
2022-03-27 10:46:13.483 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
2022-03-27 10:46:13.483 E Failed to initialize wallet RPC server
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the part I'm struggling with. I don't get why I cant bind to port 18081 on 127.0.0.1 as nothing else is bound to it (as far as I'm aware).

The *daemon* binds on port 18081 (by default) for the daemon RPC interface, and you are trying to start the *wallet* RPC binding on the same port. That's why you get the error starting `monero-wallet-rpc` with `--rpc-bind-port 18081`. Simply use another *unused* port instead here.